# Compile iptables from source make error

Tags: virtualbox, iptables, debian-squeeze

I'm trying to compile latest iptables 1.6, but I receive the following error:
(`./configure` it's OK)
then I call `make` and:

```
xtables-config-parser.y:20:28: error: libnftnl/table.h: No such file or directory
xtables-config-parser.y:21:28: error: libnftnl/table.h: No such file or directory
....
NFTNL_TABLE_FAMILY undeclared
```

I configure with:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr      \
            --sbindir=/sbin    \
            --disable-nftables \
            --enable-libipq    \
            --with-xtlibdir=/lib/xtables &&
make
```

and `make install` it's OK, but when I call `iptables` I get this error:

```
iptables symbol lookup error: iptables undefined symbol: iptc_ops
```

Debian Squeeze on VirtualBox
Kernel 4.3.3
x86
iptables version 1.6

Any ideas about how to fix it?

Comment: help me please guys

Comment: It is difficult to help you if you do not provide your machine architecture, the kernel you are running, the version of iptables you are trying to compile...

Comment: I have the same error. `./configure` threw this warning previously: `WARNING: libnetfilter_conntrack not found, connlabel match will not be built`